# Xcode - How to copy executable to new location after build?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm building a command line application using Xcode 4.

Once the build is complete the executable is located inside the default DerivedData folder. This is OK, however I'd then like to copy this file to a specific folder. I'd like this to happen regardless of the type of build (release/debug).

Can anyone please suggest a way of doing this?

As an aside, the subdirectory for my project inside DerivedData has a tag of random characters in it:

```
myProject-fnkwvtitgroivocadokaayqexhqy
```

Does anyone know if this can change over time (thus changing the location of my executable to be copied), or is it fixed for this project?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's actually a great way to automate this.  Assuming you're in your Xcode project currently, click on the project file and click on the target (since you said that it's a simple command-line program, there should only be one).

Next click on the tab Build Phases and open the triangle for Copy Files.

(If you don't see a triangle with "Copy Files", click on the + symbol to add it.)

Now in the navigator in the Products folder will be the executable that is built.  Drag this into the Copy Files build phase.

In the Copy Files little menu click on the drop menu to choose Absolute Path and below that type in the path where you'd like it to be installed.  Make sure to check "Copy only when installing" and every time you build the project and it succeeds it will copy the executable to that location.

Comment: This is not working for me... my path is correct and valid. I assume it should copy when Built for Archiving?

Comment: To make this happen "regardless of the type of build" uncheck `Copy only when installing`.

Comment: I also had trouble making this work, so I just added a Run Script and did a bash: `cp ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME} /where/ever/you/want/` It keeps the door open for further post-build processing. For a list of additional variables, check out the Xcode Build Setting reference.

Comment: This works for me in Xcode 8, would just add that if you want to place it in `/path/to/dir` then you don't have to create `dir` because Xcode will create it for you. However, you must give write permissions to the directory `to`, otherwise the build will fail.

Comment: Just a warning: I pointed the location to the same folder that had my source code. It was cleared when the executable got copied. So bye bye source code :-/

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I wanted the newly built app to be copied over existing builds in the Application's folder. In the Build Rules, add a `New Run Script Phase` to the list. I use `/bin/bash`, but you can probably use the default `/bin/sh` too. Then, I added the following code to the script.

```
cp -f -R ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME} /Applications
```

Comment: For me this is additionally moving `MyApp.swiftmodule`, `MyApp.appex`, and `MyApp.swiftmodule` into the Applications directory, in addition to `MyApp.app`. `${APPLICATION_NAME}` is empty.

Comment: You should include quotes (") around the source and destination, in case your path includes spaces. Here's an example of how to copy it just above your source folder. cp -a "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}" "${SRCROOT}/.."